# How to force background process, intercepting ctrl-z?

Tags: bash, shell, process

I have a btrfs command that intercepts Ctrl-Z, so I normally run it as

```
# btrfs command &
```

Well, today I forgot to add the `&` and I can't Ctrl Z the process. I don't need to stop the process. How do I make it go into the background?

I thought this should be simple, but for some reason it doesn't seem to be simple.

Comment: Most probably it has a reason it can not be interrupted. Therefore some `btrfs` commands have a "pause" and "resume" option.

Comment: Did you try sending `kill -SIGSTOP` to it?

Comment: @Fravadona -SIGSTOP does not stop the process

Comment: What btrfs command is it?